# Kernel security check failure when plugging in USB

Tags: windows-8, usb, drivers

Im getting an error and the laptop restarts when Im plugging in any kind of hardware in my usb ports. It doesn't matter which of the 3, I get the error regardless. I hear the sound that it connects and then the blue screen shows up with: `Kernel_security_check_failure` I've read online it has something to do with drivers but Im not very experienced with drivers. So I have no idea what to do. It's on **Windows 8** btw. I dont even know if it's certain that there is a problem with the drivers. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: copy the folder **C:\Windows\Minidump** to the desktop, create a zip, upload this zip (to a cloud service like OneDrive) and post a link to the zip here. I'll look at the dmp with the debugger

Comment: When did this started to happen? Have you installed/updated new drivers? Try to roll back drivers for USB EHCI/UHCI/OHCI (whichever you have) or remove drivers from devices you have installed recently.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I dont have this anymore. I changed OS and changed back and it hasn't occured anymore since.